# Removed sports team from Google Now keeps reappearing

Tags: google-now

I added few teams to Google Now to see how it worked.

Now I left San Francisco and I don't give a *** about the Giants' score.

I tried to remove the team by going to settings, clicking on the team, remove.
The team is removed but after a few minutes it reappears.

I have two devices running Jelly Beans so I though it was a synchronization bug. 
I removed the team on both devices at the same time, but it still keeps reappearing.

How can I definitely remove it ?

**Edit:** My Galaxy Nexus is running 4.1.2 and my Asus Transformer Infinity is running 4.1.1.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved by updating "Google Search" after the 4.2 announcement.

So it was definitely a bug :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Google Now page](http://www.google.com/landing/now/) sports cards are :

> Shown based on Web History

so I suppose there are still many links related to the Giants in your web history.

Try to go to your [google history](https://history.google.com/history/) page, search for everything related to Giants, then remove the shown items, then maybe Google Now will understand that you are no longer interested in Giants results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did not work though :/

Answer (score 2):

On top of the answer from Cédric Julien - it may be worth wiping the Google Search data & cache from Settings -> Applications.

Comment: It did not do the trick either :/